# JQuery remote validation passing extra parameter?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

My back-end validation only accepts 1 parameter: email

When I look at Firebug, I can see that the URL of the request sends 2 parameters:

```
https://example.com/rest/checkDupEmail?newEmail=myEmail%40myEmail.com&email=
```

Here is the validation code...

**HTML**:

```
<input type="textbox" name="newEmail" id="newEmail"/>
```

**JS**:

```
validator = $('#emailForm').validate({
    rules: {
        newEmail: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
                url: '/rest/checkDupEmail',
                data: { email: $('#newEmail').val()},
                dataFilter: function(data) {
                    var json = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log($('#newEmail').val());
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It's like its taking the HTML field I specify (newEmail) and sending it as a parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"It's like its taking the HTML field I specify (newEmail) and sending it as a parameter?"*

Yes, of course.  That's the default behavior of the `remote` method... it sends the data from the field being evaluated.

---

It's sending two data parameters because that's how you've set it up.

1. It's already sending the `newEmail` field's value because that's the field you've selected for `remote` validation.  This is the default behavior when using the `remote` method.
2. It's also sending the same value again as `email` because that's exactly how you've defined it with your `data` option.

   ```
   data: { email: $('#newEmail').val() },
   ```

Typically, the `data` option is only used when you want to send ***additional* data along with** the default data.  In this case, the value of the field being evaluated, `newEmail`, is the default data.

You should remove the `data` option entirely and only accept `newEmail` on your back end.  Even without JavaScript or the jQuery Validate plugin, `newEmail` would be exactly how this data naturally comes through to the server upon submit.

Remove the `data` option entirely, then either rename your markup to `email` or fix the server-side code to accept `newEmail`... do **not** send the same data twice.

**Documentation**:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Answer (score 3):

I think, that you have to change point 2, as the example of the documentation.

Instead of

```
data: { email: $('#newEmail').val() },
```

You have to use

```
data: { email: function() { return $('#newEmail').val(); } },
```

Answer (score 0):

Makes the email field required, an email and does a remote request to check if the given address is already taken. In addition, the http method is set to "post" and the username is sent alongside the email address

`$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: {
        url: "check-email.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          username: function() {
            return $( "#username" ).val();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});`